# How to select from select where group by in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am trying to select and group by column, but keeping other column with all rows. I get error message that **#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row**.

My table

[image: This is my table]

The result I want

[image]

Bellow is my query :

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE (SELECT pro_id FROM table GROUP BY pro_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT Pro_id
     , GROUP_CONCAT(Name SEPARATOR ', ') AS Name
  FROM MyTable 
 GROUP BY Pro_ID;
```

Result:

```
| PRO_ID |         NAME |
-------------------------
|      1 | john, sandra |
|      2 |          jeo |
|      3 | bruno, piter |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad9ae/2)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "merge cells" in a SQL result set as you do in your example. The best you could do is either "concat" several values in one "cell" using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function, or sort the rows to group common values together using `ORDER BY` clause.

Considering that, you need a very basic `SELECT ... ORDER BY` statement:

```
SELECT name, pro_id FROM table ORDER BY pro_id
```

Producing:

```
+---------+--------+
|  NAME   | PRO_ID |
+---------+--------+
| john    |      1 |
| sandra  |      1 |
| jeo     |      2 |
| bruno   |      3 |
| piter   |      3 |
+---------+--------+
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ea716/2